# R lme4 Plot lmer residuals ~ fitted by Factors levels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4

I would like to reproduce lmer diagnostic plots in ggplot2. Particularly, I know that for a lmer model `DV ~ Factor1 * Factor2 + (1|SubjID)` I can simply call `plot(model, resid(.)~fitted(.)|Factor1+Factor2)` to generate a lattice-based  Residuals Vs. Fitted plot, faceted for each Factor1+Factor 2 combination.

I would like to generate the same plot, but using ggplot2. I tried using `qplot(resid(model), fitted(model))` and different variations of that with different arguments, but the information about the factors needed for faceting is not coming through with this (and similar) calls.

I'd appreciate any advise to achieve this, thanks!

EDIT
The core of my question: given any lmer model, how can I create a data-frame including fitted and residual values AND the Factor information for each value? something like:

`Factor1    Factor2    Fitted    Resid
    0          0        987       654
    0          0        123       456
(...)`
I could not figure that out from lmer documentation on the `resid()` and `fitted()` functions

Comment: please make your code reproducible.

Comment: what do you want to reproduce exactly? I tried to keep the question as generic as possible precisely to obviate the need to invest too much time (mine and potential responders) on examples and demonstrations of my failure to do what I want....

Comment: Make your question specific, complete with example data.

Comment: @user53330: we do appreciate a [mcve] here.

Comment: try `broom::augment` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what we want, **a reproducible example**

```
data(Orthodont, package="nlme")
Orthodont$age <- as.factor(Orthodont$age)

model <- lmer(distance ~ age * Sex + (1|Subject), Orthodont)
plot(model, resid(.) ~ fitted(.) | age + Sex )
```

answer

```
ggplot(model, aes(.fitted, .resid)) + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ Sex + age, ncol = 4)    # (edited) I noticed fortify(model) isn't necessary.
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know ggplot also recognized lmer objects instead of dataframes, that did the trick.